# Android master detail with recycler view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, master-detail

I'm learning android and I'm just new to this concept.
This is my adapter class. It shows an error saying that the **CategoryList** is not an ***enclosing class***. I'm unable to understand the error. Please help me in uderstanding it. Thanks in advance.

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryHolder>    {

private final Context context;
private final List<Category> categories;

public CategoryAdapter(Context context, List<Category> categories) {
    this.context    = context;
    this.categories = categories;
}

@Override
public CategoryHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    // Here it's showing an error: CategoryList is not an enclosing class.
    return new CategoryHolder(layoutInflater, parent);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryHolder holder, int position) {
    final Category category = categories.get(position);
    holder.bind(category);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return categories.size();
}
}
```

This is my first fragment. It contains the list of categories such as google, facebook etc. On click on any of these items, it should open another fragment with some detail regarding the category.

```
public class CategoryList extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;

public CategoryList() { }

private void updateUI() {
    List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
    categories.add(new Category(1L, "Google", "Hello world!! This is Google."));
    categories.add(new Category(2L, "Facebook", "Hello world!! This is Facebook"));
    categories.add(new Category(3L, "WhatsApp", "Hello world!! This is WhatsApp"));
    categories.add(new Category(4L, "LinkedIn", "Hello world!! This is LinkedIn"));
    CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(getActivity(), categories);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view     = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category_list, container, false);
    recyclerView  = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_recycler);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    updateUI();
    return view;
}

public class CategoryHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Category category;
    private final TextView name;
    private final TextView description;

    public CategoryHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_layout, parent, false));
        this.name        = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
        this.description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_description);
    }

    public void bind(final Category category) {
        this.category = category;
        this.name.setText(category.getName());
        this.description.setText(category.getDescription());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment fragment = CategoryDetail.getInstance(category);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.detail_container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
}
```

This is the fragment that contains the detail of the category. For now I've not written anything in updateUI() method.

```
public class CategoryDetail extends Fragment {

private Category category;

public CategoryDetail() { }

public static CategoryDetail getInstance(Category category) {
    CategoryDetail categoryDetail   = new CategoryDetail();
    categoryDetail.category         = category;
    return categoryDetail;
}

private void updateUI() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_detail, container, false);
    updateUI();
    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: change your adapter

Comment: Change? Could you please mention the error.

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/ refer this

Answer (score 0):

You didn't create a ViewHolder class. Based on your code, you would want to create

```
public class CategoryHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
public CategoryHolder(View view) {
//code for the constructor for the ViewHolder goes here.
}
}
```